# How do I retrieve subview for a password field in RubyMotion?

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, rubymotion

Doing something like this:

```
TAG_EMAIL_TEXT_FIELD = 2
TAG_PASSWORD_TEXT_FIELD = 3

button.when(UIControlEventTouchUpInside) do
      email_field = retrieve_subview_with_tag(self, TAG_EMAIL_TEXT_FIELD)
      password_field = retrieve_subview_with_tag(self, TAG_PASSWORD_TEXT_FIELD)
```

When I enter the password in the simulator, it is shown as plain text.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what I had to do.

I needed to add a protected flag on the password field via Xcode's storyboard. That did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what gem you are using for creating your forms, I would do this with [formotion](http://clayallsopp.github.com/formotion/) which will make the creation and management of login forms very straightforward.